# Linq query to get multiple columns in c# Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get 3 columns from the linq query, I want to put 3 columns values in my viewbag.

This is my controller code.

```
public ActionResult Create(ModelName ObjectName)
{
    DocumentDeleteBAL DALObject = new DocumentDeleteBAL();
    int client_id = Convert.ToInt32(ModelName.client_id);
    int emp_id = Convert.ToInt32(ModelName.emp_id);
    int empcitizen_id = Convert.ToInt32(ModelName.empcitizen_id);

    var tm = DALObject.GetDetails(client_id, emp_id, empcitizen_id);
    return View(ObjectName);
}
```

This is my DAL code.

```
public List<ModelName> GetDetails(int client_id,int emp_id,int empcitizen_id)
{
    List<ModelName> del = (from c in db.ModelName 
                           where c.clientid == client_id
                              && c.employeeid == emp_id 
                              && c.empcitizenid == empcitizen_id 
                           select c).ToList();
    return del;
}
```

Here I am passing 3 id's and if matches I want to display clientname, employee name, nationality. I am stuck at this line

```
var tm = docdel.GetDetails(client_id, emp_id, empcitizen_id);
```

Comment: Offtopic but please do something about your naming. I already pity the guy who has to maintain the code after you :(

Comment: let me know still you have any concern. I want to return client_name,emp_name,nationality and i want to copy details to viewbag.

Comment: your 'GetDetails' method returns list object or a single object which satisfy your parameters .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already getting the full details, all you need to do is take the first object (from your collection) since it is returning `List<ts_upld_doc>` and set your *ViewBag* something like this:-

```
 var tm = docdel.GetDetails(client_id, emp_id, empcitizen_id).FirstOrDefault();
 if(tm != null)
 {
     ViewBag.Clientname = tm.Clientname;
     ..and so on
 }
```

Comment: Yes i did not know about firstordefault()... works fine

Answer (score 0):

if your GetDetails return only single object then,

```
public ModelName GetDetails(int client_id,int emp_id,int empcitizen_id)
{
  ModelName del = (from c in db.ModelName where c.clientid == client_id && c.employeeid == emp_id && c.empcitizenid == empcitizen_id select c).ToList();
    return del;
}
```

in your controller,

```
var tm = docdel.GetDetails(client_id, emp_id, empcitizen_id);
```

tm contains your model. Then,

```
viewbag. Clientname=tm. Clientname
viewbag.employee name=tm.employee name
viewbag.nationality=tm.nationality
```